# how to disable credit card data menu for payment method in bakend

Tags: magento2.3

When selecting a payment method, this menu of credit card data appears, which does not correspond to the payment method as it is not a credit card[image]

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure about this but being a maestro, or any other debit card, it should work that way, usually I insert that debit card info and do the payment. Or does that send the user to some external page like some Paypal options?

Comment: Anyway if you want to remove that, you should have installed a plugin to have maestro option, in there go to view probably /adminhtml/template and try to find the form.phtml or something like that, that form should be somewhere around and you can edit, remember to extend the file in a new module when you find it, don't edit the core file it will give problems updating